# Connect to server using python on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sockets, server

Hobbyist. Going through Lutz's 'Programming Python' on sockets/servers. Intermediate level of python knowledge but almost no knowledge of network programming.

The first example runs a server and client scripts that I can get running on my own pc using 'localhost', but I would like to run the server on a remote machine.

I set up an AWS account and an instance of EC2 and an instance of Cloud 9.

The terminology for the different web services gets too confusing for me from here. I tried playing around with permissions on the security groups page, and I can get the script running on Cloud 9, but I can't connect to it from my PC.

If someone could please steer me in the right direction (how do I get this script running via AWS and how do allow external connections to the server to interact with it?) I would be most appreciative!

Thanks.

Server script.

```
from socket import *


myHost = ''
myPort = 50007

sockobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sockobj.bind((myHost, myPort))
sockobj.listen(5)

while True:
    connection, address = sockobj.accept()
    print('Server connected by', address)
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(1024)
        if not data: break
        connection.send(b'Echo=>' + data)
    connection.close()
```

Client script

```
import sys
from socket import *
# will change localhost to server IP address, right?
serverHost = 'localhost'
serverPort = 50007

message = [b'Hello network world']

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    serverHost = sys.argv[1]
    if len(sys.argv)> 2:
        message = (x.encode() for x in sys.argv[2:])
sockobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sockobj.connect((serverHost, serverPort))

for line in message:
    sockobj.send(line)
    data = sockobj.recv(1024)
    print('Client received:', data)

sockobj.close()
```

Comment: There is no difference in ruing the script on ec2 instance or your local server. What exactly is the issue with ec2 instance?

Comment: AWS is blocking inbound traffic. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html